# native-base change button padding

Tags: react-native, native-base

I need to change the button padding to reduce the space between button text and the borders. I'm doing it as it's done when using css but it doesn't work. I also tried buttonPadding property without success as below.

```
                      <View style={{marginRight: 3}}>
                        <Button buttonPadding={1} style={{padding: 1}}  bordered small disabled={sellingDisabled} onPress={() => toggleDiscountModal()}>
                          <Text>{t('sale.discount')}</Text>
                        </Button>
                      </View>
```

Comment: style={{padding: 1}} can you try increasing the padding to 20, and see the result

Comment: that works (makes the space bigger) but the smaller amount doesn't work.

Comment: then try values in negative  numbers like style={{padding: -10}}

Comment: no that doesn't work they are still same

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to change the padding of a native base button

```
 <Button bg="red" p="2">Upload</Button>
```

the above code will give a padding of 2 in top,right,bottom and left side

for giving padding at top you can use pt as shown below:

```
 <Button bg="red" pt="2">Upload</Button>
```

Along with that you can also you px and py for giving horizontal and vertical padding respectively as shown below

```
<Button bg="red" px="2" py="4">Upload</Button>
```